# Alloy wheel corrosion damage - do I need new wheels?

Tags: wheels, corrosion

After the last couple of winters, my alloy wheels are getting quite corroded, and one of them has large flakes of the surface missing, and almost a bubbling effect in the metal.

[image]

[image]

I have read on other questions here that I could start to lose air pressure due to a poor seal so I'm assuming that at some point I need to either replace or get them sanded and re-coated, but how serious is this?

Should I do it now, or is it something that is not a major issue other than a cosmetic one for now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The potential loss of air pressure is only going to happen if you have corrosion in the area where the tyre bead seats against the wheel, not if you have surface corrosion on the outside. If the corrosion on the outside is causing air loss, the wheel is toast, but the corrosion you have on your wheel doesn't look like it's anywhere near this bad.

That said, I would get these wheels refurbished sooner rather than later simply to ensure a longer wheel life (plus an improved cosmetic appearance) and prevent further corrosion around the tyre bead area.

Comment: Timo - I meant to say thanks. I now get them sanded and powder coated every two years, and they look much nicer and are easier to wash.