# Strange look of alloy wheel (molten?!)

Tags: wheels, volvo

On my way back home today, I noticed a sound that wasn't there in the morning. As if I were, now and then, wheeling over a small gravel. I inspected the wheels, and noticed a very strange look of one of them. The sound came from the left, and the wheel in the photo is left rear. I am pretty sure this is new. Look sand feels like solidified molten aluminium, but what can it be?!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From here it looks like bubbling paint caused by corrosion under the paint.

If you press one of the bubbles with a finger nail, does it "give"? Does water come out?

Comment: Or corrosion under plating. Not aluminum melting.

Comment: Agree, just aluminium corrosion.  That will have been growing for a while.  Definitely not new.

Comment: Not just nail, but even pressing with a steel key doesn't cause any visible damage to these “bubbles”.

Comment: I thought aluminium alloys do not rust. Wrong?

Comment: @texnic Iron alloys rust, aluminum alloys corrode. See this earlier question in this stack: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/alloy-wheel-corrosion-damage-do-i-need-new-wheels

Comment: @texnic The only plausible explanation I can think of for aluminum wheels melting between the spokes is if the flux capacitor in the trunk is leaking gamma rays. But you're driving a Volvo, not a DeLorean, so forget that.  ;-)

Comment: I was wrong above: while the bubbles are strong, a friend of mine did exactly as suggested, and managed to chip off a piece of paint with a nail. Apparently, his nail is now dangerous than my key. So the theory seems to be confirmed, thank you.